# Building SCORM Compliant "2004" without Authoring Tools

Tags: scorm, lms

I am beginning a project that is working towards more options when it comes to developing eLearning and going outside the box that is normally provided by Adobe Captivate, iSpring, Storyline, Rise, and etc. I am not really sure how this will go; but I am open to anyone that has done this before.

Just starting, but I am assuming the hardest part will be the SCORM packaging and making sure all the rules and interactive modules are working within the LMS. More to follow.

Comment: Hi Joshua. Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have a specific question?